# Action RTS style video game with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to see if it's possible to make a game similar to LOL DOTA or Starcraft in the browser with javascript. I'd want it to be multiplayer for sure and I'd want it to run at 60 fps. Is this possible, or would it go too slowly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the WebGL technology along with WebSockets and probably then you could acheive satisfactory performance, but your game will be limited to browser which supports these technologies.